# Backup-files missing

Tags: backup

As I want to upgrade my Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, I made a Backup of my /home with DejaDup.

When it finished, appeared the window I share below.
I want to know if I can proceed with upgrade or first have to fix the errors.

Thank you.

[image]